# How to wrap a button in a navigation link in SwiftUI?

Tags: button, swiftui, navigation

I am new to swift, and I am trying to place a "quick exit" button on each content page of my app, the button itself is how I want it, but I am having a hard time getting the actual navigation to work. It builds, but simply does nothing when clicked.

```
struct ContentMenu: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    NavigationLink(destination: ContentView2())
                    {
                        Button(action:{} ){
                            Image(systemName: "figure.run.circle.fill")
                                .resizable(resizingMode: .stretch)
                                .font(.largeTitle)
                                .frame(width: 65, height: 65)
                                .background(Color .red)
                                .clipShape(Circle())
                            .foregroundColor(Color .black)}
                        
                    }.padding()
                        .shadow(radius: 5)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **SwiftUI**, the `NavigationLink` itself is a special type of button. So you absolutely do not need to wrap a button inside a `NavigationLink`. Simply do:

```
NavigationLink(destination: ContentView2()) {
    Image(systemName: "figure.run.circle.fill")
        .resizable(resizingMode: .stretch)
        .font(.largeTitle)
        .frame(width: 65, height: 65)
        .background(Color .red)
        .clipShape(Circle())
        .foregroundColor(Color .black)}
}.padding()
.shadow(radius: 5)
```

**Don't forget** to wrap your view inside a `NavigationStack` or a `NavigationView` *(if you plan to support iOS 15-)* in order for the navigation to work.

Comment: Thank you so much, I have tried this. Unfortunately it still doesn't work. I get the same functionality as before, it simply does nothing. Also, now the link isn't showing as clickable without the button portion of the code.

Comment: Thank you, that was the missing piece, I appreciate it!

Comment: Great and simple answer: you nailed it, thank you! :)